# add datakeyname to sql parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

On my gridview I want to activate delete button.I had added delete button to the grideview and `DeleteCommand` to `SqlDataSource`.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT rowNumber,  firstName as 'Fornavn' where shopID=@pageid order by firstName asc" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [sydShopOrder] WHERE rowNumber=@rowNumber">
    <SelectParameters><asp:QueryStringParameter Name="pageid" QueryStringField="id"/> </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

as you can see I am able to add `SelectParameters` pageid from QueryStringField.Now I want to add one more `DeleteParameters` to this `asp:SqlDataSource` which is `@rowNumber` and this is my `datakeyname` for gridview.How i can add this `datakeyname` to sql `DeleteParameters` ?

Or is there a better way?something I am missing

Comment: hope this will help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972940.aspx

Comment: My opinion is to do everything in codebehind..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a delete( as well as update) operation the data-bound control passes both current and original record values to the `SqlDataSource` control. The current values are passed in the Values dictionary.The original values are passed in the Keys or OldValues dictionaries.

What this means is that if `rowNumber` is actually a Column and should be used as a  parameter in delete command, simply set the delete command as:

```
"DELETE FROM [sydShopOrder] WHERE rowNumber=@rowNumber"
```

As long as you give each parameter the same name as the field it affects and preface it with the `@` symbol (so `FirstName` becomes `@FirstName`), you don’t need to define the parameter.
That’s because the ASP.NET data controls automatically submit a collection of parameters with the new values before triggering the update. Each parameter in the collection uses this naming convention.

One special case, when you are about to delete a data, some other user may change the same data, so in that case, possibly you won't like to delete it.

In such a case, use the property: `OldValuesParameterFormatString` of SqlDataSource as:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT rowNumber,  firstName as 'Fornavn' 
                 where shopID=@pageid order by firstName asc" 
  DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [sydShopOrder] WHERE rowNumber=@original_rowNumber">
  OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"  
> 
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Just make sure you set the `DataKeyNames` property of the GridView to include your PrimaryKeys as it is used to match the records values.Check [**`this link`**](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/10/how-to-delete-records-data-using.html).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a `DataKeyNames="pageid"` in your GridView definition? If you have set this column as primary key for your table, it should include in your GridView automatically.

**Make sure your Primary Key passed thought**

1. DataKeyNames, include your pk, the value from your select command
2. Delete/update paramname, include your datakeynames to the parametername
3. Use the param as where condition, WHERE primarykeyfield=@paramname